# 2 вопроса касательно "выбрать лучший ответ"

Tags: обсуждение, принятые-ответы, самоответы

Система навязчиво убеждает меня выбрать лучший/принятый ответ к своим вопросам. Там, где я считаю, что лучший ответ пока не дан, - понятно: выбирать не буду. Но:

1. Там, где вопрос, в принципе неплох, должен ли я его обязательно
   пометить? Или Б-г с ним, пусть пока висит, вдруг кто-либо ответит
   продуктивнее?
2. Что делать, если на уже древний вопрос мне пришлось или удалось ответить самостоятельно? Страдать нарциссизмом aka отмечать лучшим/принятым
   собственный ответ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Принятие ответа не означает, что на вопрос был дан идеальный или лучший ответ, **оно свидетельствует лишь о том, что автору было предложено решение, которое помогло лично ему**. И даже если поступят новые, более правильные ответы, автор вопроса может не поменять своего мнения и оставить принятым тот ответ, который был дан ранее.
>
> — [Что это означает, если ответ «принят»?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), справка *Stack Overflow на русском*

(жирный шрифт от меня)

---

> Там, где вопрос, в принципе неплох, должен ли я его обязательно пометить? Или Б-г с ним, пусть пока висит, вдруг кто-либо ответит продуктивнее?

Нет, не должны. Если вы так и не решили проблему за неимением хорошего решения, отсутствие галочки примерно этот факт и отразит.

Правда, для достаточно старых вопросов это может вызвать у читателей мысль "автор, видно, забил на вопрос". Можно подстегнуть интерес и продемонстрировать актуальность вопроса и спрос на ответы на него, [организовав конкурс](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty).

> Что делать, если на уже древний вопрос мне пришлось или удалось ответить самостоятельно? Страдать нарциссизмом aka отмечать лучшим/принятым собственный ответ?

Если в итоге вы собрали собственное решение и им же воспользовались, имеет смысл поставить галочку именно на собственный ответ. Никакого нарциссизма. Так бывает.

Answer (score 4):

Зеленая галка имеет две функции: исключает вопрос из списков "неотвеченных" вопросов при поиске, и указывает на ответ, действительно являющийся решением вопроса для автора. В соответствии с этим и ставьте ее, т.е когда вы хотите показать, что:

- вы больше не ищете новых ответов
- ответ вас абсолютно удовлетворяет (является протестированным рабочим решением в случае практического вопроса)

Никакой "нарциссизм" не должен приниматься во внимание. Принятие своего ответа совершенно естественно.

Answer (score 4):

1. Если вопрос вам помог, отмечайте как принятый. В будущем, если будет дан более исчерпывающий ответ, вы всегда можете галочку другому ответу отдать.
2. Отмечать свой ответ как принятый - нормальная практика.